# DESC parent rows with ASC children rows

Tags: t-sql, group-by

I have a table

```
Date   MainID    ParentID   SubID
====   ======    ========   =====
4/03   1         NULL       1
4/05   2         NULL       2
4/10   3         2          2.1
4/11   4         1          1.1
4/12   5         2          2.2
```

I'm trying to get results by DESC Date for parent nodes, but ASC SubID for children.
For example, I would like

```
Date   MainID    ParentID   SubID
====   ======    ========   =====
4/05   2         NULL       2
4/10   3         2          2.1
4/12   5         2          2.2
4/03   1         NULL       1
4/11   4         1          1.1
```

Is this possible with Group By or is it more complicated?

Comment: Is the hierarchy only two levels? What version of SQL Server? Why have you chosen this structure rather than adjacency list or `hierarchyid`?

Comment: Sql Server 2008...there can be one parent, denoted by NULL ParentID, and multiple children, denoted by an incremental SubID, which is based off of the ParentID...I chose this because I have a single table to work with and also am not familiar with adjacency lists/hierarchyid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are exist several possibilities to do so, here is quick example:

```
select *
from t
order by
COALESCE(ParentId, MainId) DESC, SubID ASC
```

this query assumes that newer rows will have higher MainId, so instead of sorting by date, you're sorting by parent ID in desc ord

sample fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/40fa7/4

Comment: @eych - It won't work if you have more than 10 children in a node. 2.10 won't be ordered correctly.

Answer (score 0):

A way that doesn't make assumptions about correlation between dates and ids and won't sort strings like `2.10` before `2.2`

```
SELECT c.*
FROM   Table1 c
       LEFT JOIN Table1 p
         ON c.SubID LIKE CAST(p.MainID AS VARCHAR(10)) + '._%'
ORDER  BY isnull(p.Date, c.Date) DESC,
          CAST('/' + c.SubID + '/' AS HIERARCHYID)
```